# dynamic font size, style as per the resolution of screen

Tags: ios, swift, uifont

I am trying to give the font size, style as per typography & weight as per the resolution of screen dynamically.

I tried:

```
title_home.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.title1)
 subtitle_home.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.title2)
 subtitle1_home.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.title2)
subtitle2_home.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.title2)
```

But am getting the text in normal regular size. I need the title as bold with some size, and it should change as per the resolution of screen.

Comment: Hi.. this code snippet you shared is fine. Can you share some other information like where your calling the code.. or if you can share the whole controller code.. i think the font property is getting overridden from some other part of your code

Comment: I am calling this code in viedidload method of viewcontroller

Comment: Are you saying you want a smaller font on an iPhone 5 and a much larger font on an iPad Pro?

Comment: And are you sure the labels fonts are not getting overridden?? i can see it working at my end. 
The fields "title_home", "subtitle_home", "subtitle1_home", "subtitle2_home" , how are you setting text to thee fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can get bold/italic/etc preferred font based on descriptor, something like this:

```
    let descriptor = UIFontDescriptor.preferredFontDescriptor(withTextStyle: .headline)
        .addingAttributes([.traits : [UIFontDescriptor.TraitKey.weight: UIFont.Weight.semibold]])

    let semiboldFont = UIFont(descriptor: descriptor, size: 0)

    print(semiboldFont)
    //<UICTFont: 0x7fe03300cc30> font-family: ".SFUIText-Semibold"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 17.00pt
```

hope that helps

Comment: is this possible for semibold??if I keep the font size same, will it vary the size as per the resolution??

Comment: Updated the answer to add more flexibility